# SaaS App Google Calendar integration and delegating access authority to read events of private calendars

Tags: elixir, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to figure out which moving parts are need to integrate my SaaS app with a company's Google calendar. The idea is to read the events of private calendars (matched on the email address of course).

As far as I can tell, I'll need an OAuth app on "my side" which will ask for consent. The part I'm struggling with, **is from the customer end**.

- How will my customer provide me with the necessary access to read all the calendars of users they've created in my SaaS app?

On the one end, it seems like a **service account** would allow that (but it seems I'd have to load that in the environment which surely cannot be the case)...looking at authentication with Goth (https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api).

I'd appreciate some help with the steps here, if anyone has a moment.

Comment: Each user will have to grant your system access to their data.   Service accounts will only work if they have a google workspace account and the users are all members of the domain.    Even then they will have to manually add each of the user as when the service account is granted access you will need to know the email of the user you want to impersonate with the service account.

Answer (score 0):

A service account with domain-wide delegation does the job I needed, in case this helps someone else.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106